# op amp random pulsing to ground

Tags: operational-amplifier, demodulation

I have simple circuit with ada4891 op amp. I am using it to demodulate ASK modulated signal. But sometimes op amp is pulsing to ground for no reason. These pulses are short (about 1 us). I have oscilloscope up to 100 Mhz but I did not measured anything on input or in power supply rail. It just randomly jumps down. And now when I am measuring it again it is working normally, but I am scared it will start again. Could you help please? Do you know why it is happening? I have MCU 1.5 cm above. Could MCU somehow disturb op amp?
This is my schematics:

[image: schematic]

Comment: Try using a lab power supply if you can, the idea is to try a known good power supply and see if the problem disappears. If so it is the power supply, if not something in your circuit. Probably something flaky in a ground connection.

Comment: The problem is the problem disappeared even with powering it via USB. Now it is working fine. I have no idea what was the cause. But I didn't change anything.

Comment: Golden rule of development: if you didn't fix it, it's still broken. Probably flaky connections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be difficult to find random 1us interference particularly when you don’t know where to look.

When this happened in my early days to me I looked around and saw my temperature controlled Weller soldering iron and with a quiet click sound of a  relay, I said, that’s it! Radiated EMI pulse from a dry contact inductive load during turn off with dt approaching zero except for air gap capacitance.

Your supply filtering has a ridiculous amount of filtering so the cabling might make the difference on ground shift noise, but the line side mass massive inductance.  This of course doesn’t work without some series DCR coil resistance of a few Ohms and with just that R, you don’t need the inductor when your load is on the order of a 1k Ohm. In theory with an ideal L that would produce a Q of 1000 at a couple hundred Hz, which isn’t possible maybe a hundred or so.  but that can’t possibly create a 1us pulse, but if you had some motor noise on the supply, it would ring at that frequency and be amplified by 40dB or so with this high Q series LC circuit. So I would prefer a cost reduction and a 1st order RC filter or CMOS LDO if necessary from unknown noise levels but this can be managed by knowing your PSRR and all your load ripple.

[image]

Comment: This is killing me because it is part of my thesis and it might stab me in the back at the presentation. One thing I noticed it started randomly ticking after I started internal timer in MCU. But why it would now stopped?

Comment: Keep looking....  try to make interference, of anything that might be root cause and include this as a side note in presentation. Also consider your input is not differential or “BALun” ced. ;) so where are your source and connections .

Comment: Ok, so I find out when I connect something with big capacitor inside, next to USB where is my circuit, it jumps down once. I measured about 200 mV decline from 5V on power bus. I don't know why it was jumping repeatedly back then and why I could not measure any noise on power bus or input signals but this was the problem too. So I added LDO before filter and now when I connect some big load to next USB, it don't jumps anymore. Maybe it solves also that random jumping problem, maybe it's related. I was playing with it all day and I didn't see it jumping. Thank you for your answers!